# Where to put @Nullable on methods with nullable return types?

Tags: java, annotations, nullable

When using `javax.annotation.Nullable` to mark methods as "potentially returning `null` value", where to put the `@Nullable` annotation?  On the method, or return type?

Is there any technical difference, or is this strictly a style issue?

**Style A:**

```
@Nullable
public Object blah() { ... }
```

**Style B:**

```
public @Nullable Object blah() { ... }
```

Comment: `A` is much more readable. You can also look into Java core or Google java libraries, and you'll see the use the first style.
If you have multiple annotations for that method, Style B will get worse.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is strictly a style issue.

No matter where you write the annotation in the source code, the annotation is actually on the method.  That's because of the `@Target` meta-annotation on the definition of `javax.annotation.Nullable`, which makes `javax.annotation.Nullable` a method annotation.  You are allowed to write the annotation in either location, because 
the Java Language Specification grammar permits method annotations to be interspersed with method modifiers such as `public`.

I consider it clearer to place the annotation before the return type.  After all, it's the return type that is non-null.  It doesn't make sense to say that a method itself is non-null.

Placing the annotation before the return type has another important benefit:  your code is compatible with versions of `Nullable` that are defined as type annotations.  Type annotations were introduced in Java 8.  They are more expressive than method annotations, and they enable more powerful checking.  For example, the `Nullable` annotations supported by Eclipse and the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org) are type annotations.

Answer (score -2):

Option type will do the trick for you. A return type of Option indicates that the method may return an Object, or it may return a special value of type None or null.

Comment: Option hasn't been added to replace all null values. Have a look at this article: https://dzone.com/articles/optional-ispresent-is-bad-for-you